# meaning of "easier on the nerves"

Tags: idioms, phrase-meaning

What does it mean when we say "something is easier on the nerves"? Does it mean "it is easier to withstand"?

Comment: Have you done any research, such as a web search, to investigate this?  I'm voting to close for lack of research.

Comment: Soft "easy listening" music is easier on the nerves than hard rock.  Relaxing on the beach is easier on the nerves than driving in bumper-to-bumper traffic.

Answer (score -1):

easier to stomach?

strictly speaking, it means something that has roughly the same meaning but is less disturbing. Euphemisms are a good example

my wife died, but I prefer to say that she is no longer with us

no one misunderstands, but it is less socially awkward